# ggplot line plot by group and sub-group without a facet

Tags: r, plot, grouping, line

I am wondering if I am able to graph separate lines for 2 variables without using the grid function. I would prefer the 4 lines on one graph than 2 lines in 2 grids. Its ok if I can't but thought I would ask.

My data is as follows:

```
nd<-data.frame(Machine = c(2,2,3,3,2,2,3,3), 
Source = c("tube", "machine","tube", "machine","tube", "machine","tube", "machine"),
Time=c(0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2), 
Count=c(224000, 107000, 850000, 940000, 610000,116000, 1160000, 1100000))
```

and this code gives me what I want with a facet...

```
ggplot(data=nd, aes(x=Time, y=Count, group=Machine, color=Machine)) +
 geom_line(aes(group=Machine))+ geom_point()+facet_grid(~Source)
```

Is there an alternative to this?

P.S. even though Machine is a factor variable why is my legend showing it as continuous?

Comment: ggplot(data=nd, aes(x=Time, y=Count, color=interaction(Machine,Source))) + geom_line() + geom_point()

Comment: you're welcome :)

Comment: @StupidWolf you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

One quick way is to use the `interaction` function, which paste your two variables with a "."

```
ggplot(data=nd, aes(x=Time, y=Count, color=interaction(Machine,Source))) +
geom_line() + geom_point() +
scale_color_manual("groups",
values=c("#61d4b3","#fdd365","#fb8d62","#fd2eb3"))
```

[image]